How to share models between ASP.NET Web API and Blazor applications?
I'm currently in the process of migrating an ASP.NET MVC project to Blazor, and I'm seeking advice on the best approach for sharing data models between my ASP.NET Web API project and the new Blazor client application.
In my existing ASP.NET Web API project, I have defined several data models (Manga, MangaChapterViewModel, etc.) for interacting with the database. As part of the migration process, I want to reuse these models on the client side within my Blazor application without duplicating them.
I'm considering whether to create a separate class library project to store these shared models or if there's a better approach available. Additionally, I'm interested in understanding how to handle data serialization/deserialization, loading data via HTTP requests, and managing the data models on the client side within a Blazor context.
I would greatly appreciate it if anyone has experience with a similar migration scenario or can provide advice, examples, or best practices. Thank you!

Putting your model classes into a separate class library is the best approach. At the same time, I'd also recommend "decoupling" your model classes from the underlying database entities - don't expose the database tables / entities directly - use a separate set of ("independent") model classes, so that your logical model doesn't have to exactly match your database structure. This gives you more flexibility and stability.

@marc_s You mean, using DTOS? And, thank you.

Call them DTOs, or "models" or whatever you like ;-) - but yes, I'd recommend not directly exposing your database entity classes, but put an "independent" layer of model classes / DTOs on top
